# Proof Check : If $\sum a_k$ and $\sum b_k$ converge, does $\sum$ $\sqrt{(a_k)^2 + (b_k)^2}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The claim is for positive real sequences. I haven't found a counter counter-example so I attempted a proof but I'm really not sure if what I have done is valid. I'd really appreciate some feedback on this proof and ,if it's incorrect, some hints.

Proof: For any positive integer k, we either have 0 $\lt$ $a_k$ $\le$ $b_k$ or 0 $\lt$ $b_k$ $\lt$ $a_k$.

Let V = {k :  $a_k$ $\le$ $b_k$}
and let U = {k :  $a_k$ $\gt$ $b_k$}

Then if n $\in$ V then 0 $\lt$ $\sqrt{(a_n)^2+(b_n)^2}$ $\le$ $\sqrt2$ $b_n$ and so $\sum_{k \in V}$ $\sqrt{(a_k)^2 + (b_k)^2}$ converges by comparison test.

Using a similar argument we can show $\sum_{k \in U}$ $\sqrt{(a_k)^2 + (b_k)^2}$ converges.

Then we can sum these together which shows that $\sum$ $\sqrt{(a_k)^2 + (b_k)^2}$ converges.

Comment: $\sqrt {a_k^{2}+b_k^{2}} \leq a_k+b_k$.

Comment: Ohhh thank you. I didn't realise it was so simple

Comment: As for your argument, its subtle. You have to add that those two series are absolutely convergent, and so their sum converge absolutely, and therefor you are allowed to change the order of summation. (In general, we cannot change order of summation). But all in all your proof works fine.

Comment: @FreeZe Thank you for the advice. For some reason this was the first idea I came up with when I saw the question so I'm glad that it worked - even though if it was unnecessary.